# object is not callable but I do not know how to divide the module into each other

Tags: python, module

```
 import mains
 print(mains.hi())
 import parsogv2
 print(parsogv2.gets())

 priliv = mains()/parsogv2()
```

I have this trouble 'module' object is not callable. I want to split the values I get in modules How to do it better ? Combine them into one module or can I do as I wanted in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you've been trying to do is divide the return values of `mains.hi()` and `parsogv2.gets()`, then what you should be doing is:

```
priliv = mains.hi()/parsogv2.gets()
```

The error you've been receiving, informing you that a module is not callable, is a result of your attempt to call the actual modules (`mains` and `parsogv2`) instead of the functions they contain (`mains.hi` and `parsogv2.gets`), which I assume is what you were going for.